# How to sum a column with a condition on another column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table (vh_allocation) like bellow

| vh_name | va_date | trip_no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Vehicle-01 | 2019-01-15 | 1 |
| Vehicle-01 | 2019-01-15 | 1 |
| Vehicle-01 | 2019-01-16 | 1 |
| Vehicle-02 | 2019-01-17 | 0 |

My expected result

| vh_name | va_date | trip_no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Vehicle-01 | 2019-01-15 | 2 |
| Vehicle-01 | 2019-01-16 | 1 |
| Vehicle-02 | 2019-01-17 | 0 |

I am using `(sum(trip_no) over (partition by va_date )) trip_sum` query but get the bellow result

| vh_name | va_date | trip_no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Vehicle-01 | 2019-01-15 | 2 |
| Vehicle-01 | 2019-01-15 | 2 |
| Vehicle-01 | 2019-01-16 | 1 |
| Vehicle-02 | 2019-01-17 | 0 |

Comment: From what i can see, your approach seems correct. Can you post your entire select query so that we can understand where this is going wrong..??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use just `sum()` aggregation and `group by`

```
select vh_name ,va_date ,sum( trip_no) as trip_no
from tablename
group by vh_name , va_date
```

Comment: #fa06--- yes you are right, i include all sub query into a one view then apply group by and get the result.